# Mongoose aggregate if _id match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query ,that finds in Video Model , which get the views , but i need those views according to userId, like userId="1xxxxxxxxx13",
is it possible?

```
Video.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          totalViews: {
            $sum: {
              $cond: [{ $eq: ["$userId", id] }, "$views", 0],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }
  );
```

quer, gives me zero views but there views there are views of video from tht userId
here is schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ....
  thumbnail: { type: String, required: false },
  title: { type: String, required: false },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  views: { type: Number },
  ....
  
});
videoSchema.index({ title: "text" });
module.exports = mongoose.model("Video", videoSchema);
```

i need to filter videos of specific user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are counting the views for each user.

You can do as below. Group by user id and count the views. It returns user wise viewCounts

```
 [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: $userId,
          totalViews: {
            $sum: "$views",
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you want to filter user wise, you can add `{ $match : { "userId" : id}}`  as your first pipeline in the aggregation.